# UnityPlayer as a SubView with Transparent Background? (Unity Game Engine)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, transparency, subview, glsurfaceview

I am trying to do the following on Android (then possibly on iOS) and any advices will be appreciated:

Overlaying UnityPlayer view on top of Native Android view where only the 3D objects being drawn and no camera background (transparent background)

My current progress:

So far I managed to use my Unity3D project as library into another Android project and assign UnityPlayer view to a FrameLayout on top of another Android view but the camera background color showing... I tried changing the clear flag option to depth only but it didn't work.

I also managed to use a separate GLSurfaceView which I assigned class extending UnityPlayer and implementing GLSurfaceView.Renderer to as the renderer but I am still getting opaque background.

My code as follows:

```
// the class extending the player
class CustomUnityPlayer extends UnityPlayer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public CustomUnityPlayer(ContextWrapper context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        super.onDrawFrame(gl);
    }
}

// inside  OnCreate function:
        m_UnityPlayer = new CustomUnityPlayer(this);
        int glesMode = m_UnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        m_UnityPlayer.init(glesMode, false);

        mUnityView = new GLSurfaceView(getApplication());
        mUnityView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mUnityView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        mUnityView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        mUnityView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        mUnityView.setRenderer(m_UnityPlayer);
        mUnityView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.UnityView);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        layout.addView(mUnityView, 0, lp);
```

Am I missing something and is it even possible? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some attempts...removing mUnityView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true); did the trick for me (works on Unity 4.2 and below... not in Unity 4.3 and above)

Comment: I have a question for you Question maker/answerer. I read that it was possible to do what you say in the your question, but as of Unity 4.3 it wasn't possible to have transparent backgrounds in a scene, and if you tried to do that you would get a black background. Did this example you are providing is for Unity 4.2? Is it possible to do this on Unity 4.3+?

Thank you.

Comment: @JavaZava yes this works only with unity 4.2 and below... not unity 4.3 since they changed how the view is constructed (they moved from java to C++)... i will edit the answer to clarify it